# Where should I list my natural language skills?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

On the Jobs site, where should I put the fact that I speak another natural language? In my personal statement?

Comment: What I want to know is what *unnatural* languages you can speak?

Comment: @Will maybe the OP is fluent in Klingon?

Comment: @Bugs I was hoping we had a R'lyehian speaker around.  I mean, just in case *he comes*. (And whoever stripped zalgo text from the comment editor, I hate you.)

Comment: No Klingon here I'm afraid. Just French and English!

Comment: I tried to talk to snakes on python, but they do not understand me. I think they already use the 3.x version.
Sign language, for example, an unnatural language seriously speaking.

Comment: @nick_gabpe did you try `import parseltongue`?